# Using System.Linq.Dynamic, need to get results from dynamic query/table as IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I need to select records from various keyword tables based on a parameter kwdType. Instead of duplicating the lines of code, I am  trying to use dynamic linq to set the table type based on a switch statement and querying dynamically. I don't find any way to get the results as IEnumerable. I need to send these results to another function that accepts only IEnumerable. Any tips please.

```
        Type returnType = null;
        switch (kwdType.ToLower())
        {
            case "class1":
                returnType = typeof(TblClass1);
                break;
            case "class2":
                returnType = typeof(TblClass2);
                break;
            case "class3":
                returnType = typeof(TblClass3);
                break;

        }
        //I need to get the results as IEnumerable
        MYDB.Set(returnType).AsQueryable().Where("Active=@0", "Y")

       return new PagedResponse<returnType>(MYDB.Set(returnType).AsQueryable().Where("Active=@0", "Y"), pageIndex, pageSize);
```

Here is the error

cannot convert from system.linq.iqueryable to system.collections.generic.IEnumerable

Comment: What is the type of MYDB?

Comment: As an FYI: `IQueryable` => database query, `IEnumerable` => in memory query. In your code, you never executed the query on the database

Comment: It is a type extended from DbContext

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add something like `.ToArray()`or `.ToList()` at the end of your last line of code to get what you need.